# Vertical scroll bar of tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode4.3

I have a `UITableView`, upon which I have placed an `UIImageView`, which scrolls vertically when the table is dragged, up or down depending on how it is dragged. (The image is separate and has not relation to what is present cells of the table view.)

`UIScrollViewDelegate` has been used for vertical scrolling.

Is there any way, the image can be moved along with the vertical scroll bar when the table is dragged? If so, how can this be achieved?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481826/dragging-an-uiview-inside-uiscrollview) link. Hope it is useful

Comment: safecase, i'm looking for something different, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve is something similar to the scroller of Path.app.
Hava a look at this control: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/knpathtableviewcontroller
It's Open source and achieves this.

Comment: larsschwegmann! Exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks a lot.