# how to perform double tap on imageView

Tags: objective-c

I have work on touch event but that would be not work because of I take imageView in ScrollView so,that when I touch the image that directly work scrollview but not work touch on image so give any suggestion and source code which is apply in my code.....

Answer (score 1):

As frauen1 says in their answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042116/19679):

> 1) In the UIScrollView class, set the value of canCancelContentTouches
>   to NO - this tells the UIScrollView class to allow touches within
>   subviews (or, in this case, in subviews of subviews).
>
> 2) In my "card" class, set exclusiveTouch to YES - this tells the
>   subview it owns the touches inside of it.

Now it will allow double tap on ImageView with following code

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
    self.imgViewGVC.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapView:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.ImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
```