# Get TouchEvent to the subview of my scrollview iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dragging an UIView inside UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481826/dragging-an-uiview-inside-uiscrollview)

My app has a scrollview which contains progressBar and imageviews etc.

Now i want to add **TapGestureRecognizer** only to the imageviews that are in my scroll view.

i am able to add **TapGestureRecognizer** to my total scrollview but not my images which are in scrollview

**NOTE:** Want to add TapGestureRecognizer only to my imageviews that are subviews of my scrollView, not to entire scrollView.

Here is my code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[myScrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: why you are not adding this to your imageView, have you tried and what issue you faced in that? What code you have used to add this to your imageViews?

Comment: I agree with @rishi, if you want the subview to respond to the gesture, add the gesture directly to it.

Comment: @rishi i already tried like "UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];" for my imageview but that was not worked

Comment: @laxcha - you need to set userInteractionEnabled of your imageView to True, by default that if false.