# UIGestureRecognizers Dependencies

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, touches

I have a `UIView` that has a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in it like this:

```
    movementGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [movementGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [movementGestureRecognizer setMinimumPressDuration:0.0f];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:movementGestureRecognizer];
```

Has you can see by the name of it, it's used to, as soon, as I long press the `UIView`, I am able to move it around.

The thing is, I want also to be able to add some other kind of gestures, for example:

```
       optionsGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(options:)];
        [optionsGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:optionsGestureRecognizer];
```

The problem is that, I am not able to call `options:` because the `movementGestureRecognizer` is "sucking" all the gestures. Is there are a way to prevent, or cancel the `movementGestureRecognizer` or delay it?

---

**Edit 1.0**

I am able to call `options:` from the `TapGestureRecognizer` if I do the following:

```
    [movementGestureRecognizer setMinimumPressDuration:0.1f];
```

Still, it's not the perfect solution in terms of usability...

Comment: try by setting number of taps required for long press to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come with a solution by doing the following:

1) Implementing a "state machine" on my `UIView`, by disabling and enabling `UIGestureRecognizers` based on the state of it.

2) Use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for moving the `UIView's` around.

3) And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481826/dragging-an-uiview-inside-uiscrollview?rq=1) question.

Comment: Interesting! I'm also looking for a "finite state machine" solution for managing the state of a rather complex menu. If i may ask, did you write your "state machine" from scratch or did you consider using something like the [State Machine Compiler](http://smc.sourceforge.net/)? Or would the State Machine Compiler be overkill for your purpose?

Comment: There are 3 states on my `UIView`: normal state, the add new sub `UIView` state, resize state. Based on this 3 states, I enable and disable the `UIGesturesRecognizers`, so they don't overlap each other. At the moment I have 6 `UIGesturesRecognizers` and everything works fine. I also did some stuff with the UIScrollGesture so it doesn't get in "the way" while you are doing your stuff with the other Gestures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but can you try to implement the `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` delegate like this maybe:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

additionally you can specify dependencies between gesture recognizers like this:

```
[optionsGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: movementGestureRecognizer];
```

I'd suggest that you read up the details in the [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)!

You can find also a good post elaborating on the very same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627934/simultaneous-gesture-recognizers-in-iphone-sdk/3319426#3319426)!

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a tap and a long press is in how long you hold your finger down before releasing it from the touch surface.  Therefore, you would want to have a minimum press duration of greater than 0.

In addition, you can do the following:

```
movementGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
movementGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
```

This would allow the system to recognize taps as well as long presses.

Comment: Doesn't change anything adding the delayTouches.