# Dragging an UIImageViews inside UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c

In my app i have UIScrollview and multiple uiimageviews inside it, here i have done this all, i want to allow user to rearrange the uiimageviews around uiscrollview. 
i.e **LIKE GALLERY VIEW IN ANDROID**. What is the best way to do this.
Here is the code how im adding uiimageview to scrollview

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myview.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[myview.layer renderInContext:context];

UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 


myimageview.image=screenShot;

[myscrollview addSubview:myimageview];
```

Comment: what's going on in that last line there, you seem to be calling a method `myimageview` on `myscrollview`?

Comment: check out the answers posted for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481826/dragging-an-uiview-inside-uiscrollview?rq=1

Comment: myscrollview.canCancelContentTouches=NO;
    
  [myimageview setExclusiveTouch:YES];  i have done this but not working