# How to program draggable tiles for a word game?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, draggable, tile

I am an iOS programming newbie (reading several books on the subject simultaneously) and I would like to develop a (yet another) word game.

Coming from Flash/Flex programming background I was first expecting the tiles to be best bundled as gif or png assets.

But then I have taken a look (by using iFunbox) at the popular word games (Lexulous, Wordament, Words with Friends, Ruzzle, ...) and **none of them** is doing that:

[image]

That is none of the many apps I've looked at includes any letter pieces as images.

**So my question is** what would be the recommended approach (in Xcode 5 and with no additional SDKs like Cocos2d or Sparrow) to create a letter tile for a word game?

On a tile I'd like to have

- the center-aligned letter (obviously!),
- then an index in a corner displaying the letter value
- and then another index for a total word value

When touched I'd like to make the tile a bit larger and add a shadow underneath it.

Should my tile class be a `UIView` (can they be dragged around, grow and have shadows?)

Should I use a .nib file for the tile?

For dragging I have found a good suggestions already: [Dragging an UIView inside UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481826/dragging-an-uiview-inside-uiscrollview)

But what I really would like to know here is: if `UIView` would make a good tile (performance- and feature-wise) or should I go for another base class (like maybe some shapes)?

Comment: UIView would be a good container - also consider UIControl as it offers some extra touch handling opportunities (beginTracking,continueTracking, isTracking etc..) along with the ability to add target action events

Comment: UIControl is also good because you can add those views to a xib and set their class. Then you can set IBActions (touchupinside, dragoutside, etc) from that view in the xib if needed. Can be very handy in certain situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes UIView would be a good container.
Create a subclass of UIView, say TileView, put in some labels, image view and a button over it, override buttons UIControlEventTouchDown, UIControlEventTouchUpInside, UIControlEventTouchDragInside events to help U navigate the view in its parent. Put the TileView in some container (your view controller view or where U would like it to be) and this is basically it.

```
-(void)btnPressed:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;

    oldPoint = point;
}

-(void)btnRelesed:(id)sender
{
// stop moving code
}

-(void)btnDragged:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    dx = point.x - oldPoint.x;
    dy = point.y - oldPoint.y;

    oldPoint = point;

    // set tile view center position using 
    CGPoint ptCenter;
    ptCenter = self.view.center;
    ptCenter.x = ptCenter.x + dx;
    ptCenter.y = ptCenter.y + dy;
    self.view.center = ptCenter;
}
```

self.view is your TileView and its self.view cause U have ovrriden UIView class ;)

Comment: Thanks, so I need a translucent Button to handle dragging?

Comment: It is one way to do it, yep. U do something like this: